# Java Directory Structure

Tags: java

Given the following directory structure:

```
bigProject
|--source
| |--Utils.java
|
|--classes
|--
```

And the following command line invocation:
javac -d classes source/Utils.java
Assume the current directory is bigProject, what is the result?

```
A. If the compile is successful, Utils.class is added to the source directory.
B. The compiler returns an invalid flag error.
C. If the compile is successful, Utils.class is added to the classes directory.
D. If the compile is successful, Utils.class is added to the bigProject directory.
```

Answer: C

Can anyone explain me, why the answer is C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-d classes` command line switch tells the compiler to store compiled code in `classes` folder.

See [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/javac.html) of javac:

> -d directory
>
> Set the destination directory for class files. The destination directory must already exist; javac will not create the
> destination directory. If a class is part of a package, javac puts the
> class file in a subdirectory reflecting the package name, creating
> directories as needed. For example, if you specify -d /home/myclasses
> and the class is called com.mypackage.MyClass, then the class file is
> called /home/myclasses/com/mypackage/MyClass.class.
>
> If -d is not
> specified, javac puts the class file in the same directory as the
> source file.

Answer (score 1):

If you run `javac` without any arguments, help content gets printed

```
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
where possible options include:
  -g                         Generate all debugging info
  -g:none                    Generate no debugging info
  -g:{lines,vars,source}     Generate only some debugging info
  -nowarn                    Generate no warnings
  -verbose                   Output messages about what the compiler is doing
  -deprecation               Output source locations where deprecated APIs are used
  -classpath <path>          Specify where to find user class files and annotation processors
  -cp <path>                 Specify where to find user class files and annotation processors
  -sourcepath <path>         Specify where to find input source files
  -bootclasspath <path>      Override location of bootstrap class files
  -extdirs <dirs>            Override location of installed extensions
  -endorseddirs <dirs>       Override location of endorsed standards path
  -proc:{none,only}          Control whether annotation processing and/or compilation is done.
  -processor <class1>[,<class2>,<class3>...]Names of the annotation processors to run; bypasses default discovery process
  -processorpath <path>      Specify where to find annotation processors
  -d <directory>             Specify where to place generated class files
  -s <directory>             Specify where to place generated source files
  -implicit:{none,class}     Specify whether or not to generate class files for implicitly referenced files
  -encoding <encoding>       Specify character encoding used by source files
  -source <release>          Provide source compatibility with specified release
  -target <release>          Generate class files for specific VM version
  -version                   Version information
  -help                      Print a synopsis of standard options
  -Akey[=value]              Options to pass to annotation processors
  -X                         Print a synopsis of nonstandard options
  -J<flag>                   Pass <flag> directly to the runtime system
```

And `-d` says       `-d <directory>             Specify where to place generated class files`